# Consuming webservice from wsdl with basic authentication from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

I have a  WSDL file. I want to consume webservice from this WSDL. I have added service reference by using this WSDL and created proxy. I have created required parameter for invoking my service method. Actually webservice is protected by a basic authentication. But in the client proxy no option found to provide the user name and password. How could I invoke webservice? 
I want to provide basic authentication credentials.

I am getting the following error when invoking service method without giving credentials.

```
 System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. 
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxxxxx";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxxxx";
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIbrary/ms733775.aspx